# Two indicated sets (graphs) form a separation of $X$ because neither contains a limit point of the other

Tags: general-topology

The example is from Munkres Topology section 23. What are the limit points of these two sets (graphs)?

[image]

Comment: Each of the two graphs are closed, so they are their own sets of limit points.

Answer (score 0):

Every point in the graphs are the limit points, and only those points are the limit points. Since the graphs do not cross, neither contains a limit point of the other.